# Fast site creation with CSOM

Tags: development, csom, sharepoint-on-prem

I am working on a small api that creates site collections in SharePoint 2019.

Since SharePoint 2016, fast site creation feature is available with "New-SPSite" command in PowerShell (-CreateFromSiteMaster flag).

I am wondering if this feature can be used with CSOM... (Or maybe it's configured by default with CSOM?)

Below part of my code:

```
var tenant = new Tenant(context);
var siteOp = tenant.CreateSite(siteCollProps);
context.Load(siteOp);
context.ExecuteQuery();
```

Thanks for your answer!

Answer (score 0):

Since it's not mentioned in Microsoft's CSOM documentation, I would recommend configuring the Fast Site Creation if it isn't already and doing your own tests to see if it slower or the same speed as the Fast Site Creation via PowerShell.

Answer (score 0):

No, this feature cannot be used with CSOM.

Besides, your code is working for SharePoint Online. It would not work in SharePoint On-prem 2016.